# SSL Cert on proxy vs SSL Cert on Origin Server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

So I am setting up a reverse-proxy that will be visible from internet. I will install an intermediate CA signed SSL Cert on the reverse-proxy. The reverse-proxy will terminate the original SSL connection but will do another SSL connection to the origin server over and forward the application traffic.

If my domain is `acme.com` then the SSL Cert on my reverse-proxy will have a `cn: acme.com`. My origin server will have a self-signed SSL Cert. My question is should I use the same `cn: acme.com` on the SSL cert installed on the origin server even though it is not directly accessible by end user? What are the pros and cons of not using `cn: acme.com` on the self-signed origin server?

Comment: *"The reverse-proxy will not terminate the SSL connection ..."* - this means that the proxy will only pass the encrypted data from the client to the server so that end-to-end-encryption between client and server is kept. In this case the proxy would not need a certificate by itself. Or do you mean that the proxy will terminate the SSL connection from the client and then create a new SSL connection from the proxy to the server?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sounds like I have the second scenario. The DNS will resolve `acme.com` to the reverse-proxy (and not the origin server). The connection between reverse-proxy and the origin server is further encrypted. So I guess reverse-proxy does terminate the SSL connection from the client and then create a new SSL connection from the proxy to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the certificate for the internal server does not matter if explicitly trust this specific certificate for example by fingerprint in your reverse proxy (i.e. not blindly trust everything). But trusting a specific certificate means that you also need to change which certificate you trust if the internal setup changes (i.e. new certificate). This can be especially a problem if you don't fully control the internal setups.

It would scale better if you don't use self-signed certificates but instead certificates issued by an internal CA. In this case it is enough to trust the internal CA in your proxy as long as the subject of the certificate matches the domain. This makes it possible to change the internal certificate independently from the proxy setup as long the subject still matches the domain and the certificate is still issued by the trusted internal CA.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, that answers my question.